# Как передавать данные из js в php POST запросом?

Tags: javascript, php

Имеется форма на сайте и веб сервис, который получает данные этой формы и возвращает по ним ответ. Js считывает поле формы, отправляет их в php следущим образом:

```js
async function cardBalanceRequest(){
  let number = document.querySelector('.bonus_modal #block__bonus').value;
  if(number !== '' && number.match(/^([0-9]{7})$/)){

    url = '/assets/templates/card_balance.php';
    try {
      let response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        },
        body: 'number='+number //JSON.stringify()
      });
      const json = await response.json();
```

php получает введенную строку следующим образом:

```php
$number = $_POST['number'];
```

Подскажите пожалуйста - как можно записать в body более одной переменной и после считать из в php? Пробовал передавать в виде массива, 2мя переменными подряд с различными разделителями, сработала только вот такая запись, в последствии разделенная с помощью explode()

```js
let very_unikalno_data = number+';'+ordernumber;
/*немного кода*/
body: 'number='+very_unikalno_data
```

Comment: Рекомендую использовать стандартный объект `FormData` для формирования тела запроса (конечно, можно и JSONом сериализовать - но рано или поздно тебе потребуется еще и файлики передавать на сервер, поэтому лучше сразу же, изначально привыкать к хорошему). Пример вроде был в статье MDN о `fetch` (а если нет - он гуглится на раз).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если тело отсылается через `JSON.stringify()`, то в PHP:

```
$rawJson = file_get_contents('php://input');
$postData = json_decode($rawJson, true);
```

Можно отправлять через `FormData`

```
let fd = new FormData();
fd.append("var1", 'test')
fd.append("var2", "Hello World");
fetch('/servers/server.php', {method: "POST", body: fd})
```

Тогда на PHP прилетит как обычно через `$_POST`

Comment: Сделал с FormData как вы писали выше, но чтение в php строкой $number = $_POST["var1"]; возвращает null, не могли бы подсказать в чем может быть беда?